# UWP Community Toolkit, controle DataGrid : como alinhar conteúdo de célula à direita

Tags: uwp, datagrid

Eu tenho uma coluna numérica num [DataGrid](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid) que eu quero que seu conteúdo esteja alinhado à direita. Eu [li a documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/), principalmente [Customizable templates and styling for cells, rows and headers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/controls/datagrid_guidance/styling_formatting_options#4-customizable-templates-and-styling-for-cells-rows-and-headers) onde terminei com este código para conseguir que o conteúdo da célula fique alinhado à direita:

```
<controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="controls:DataGridCell">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Right"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</controls:DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Como é de se esperar, este código realmente faz o que eu quero, mas com todas as células. Eu quero que apenas a coluna numérica tenha essa propriedade, e só ela, mas eu tenho sido incapaz de conseguir isso.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Já tentou HorizontalContentAlignment?

Comment: @MarcosBrinner, obrigado pelo comentário. O resultado é o mesmo, todas as células à direita.